# WEBAUDIO17014: Decoding error: The stream provided is corrupt or unsupported while using audioCtx.decodeAudioData() in Edge browser

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, decoder, opus

I am trying to decode opus file using WebAudio API's decodeAudioData() method in Edge browser.But I am getting this error WEBAUDIO17014: Decoding error: The stream provided is corrupt.
Edge version details:
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

I am doing something very similar to the below example:This is also giving same error in Edge browser.
https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/

Please note this works fine in rest of the browsers.

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://fetch-streamaudio.anthum.com/audio/opus/decode- test-64kbps.opus', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {

      },
      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.error});
  }

  request.send();
}
```

It should decode the opus audio arraybuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Edge [does not yet support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/oggcontainer/) Opus in an Ogg container, however [since 2016 it has supported](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/18/webm-vp9-and-opus-support-in-microsoft-edge/) Opus in a WebM container using MSE.  Chrome and Firefox also support Opus in WebM, so you may want to switch to a WebM container in order to work with all three browsers.